# What concept is being exhibited in this macro wrapping?

Tags: c, macros

A bunch of code just got handed over to me and I got baffled by macros in the header. I could not understand what they are for:

```
#define WRAPPER_MACRO(symbol) symbol
#define ANOTHER_SYMBOL WRAPPER_MACRO(ANOTHER_SYMBOL)
#define PREFIXED_ANOTHER_SYMBOL WRAPPER_MACRO(PFX_ANOTHER_SYMBOL)
```

Why do this? What is the benefit?

Edit: This is not the actual verbatim code from my codebase but it has the same template. I just replaced macro names.

Comment: This should probably be on SO, not programmers. Also, you're going to want to show the real macros, because I'm going to guess that there's some token-pasting (##)  or string-izing (#) operators in there.

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael said, we'll need to see the real macros to know for sure. But without them, I'm willing to take a few guesses that might help you out.

The macro nesting is probably a [stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) thing. This bit of code is from a codebase I maintain:

```
// As per http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html:
// "If you want to stringify the result of expansion of a macro argument, you
// have to use two levels of macros."
#ifndef STRINGIFY
#define STRINGIFY(s) TOSTRING(s)
#define TOSTRING(s) #s
#endif
```

I'm also guessing your `PREFIXED_ANOTHER_SYMBOL` macro is doing something similar to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace), using the `#` or `##` preprocessor directives to prepend a certain symbol to whatever you feed the macro.

Comment: Hmmm. Looked through the code. There are no stringification uses. No definitions using anything like `#s` or `##s`. What also confuses me the most is `#define ANOTHER_SYMBOL WRAPPER_MACRO(ANOTHER_SYMBOL)` which is almost recursive but I guess macro preprocessing isn't recursive because based on the results of preprocessing, `ANOTHER_SYMBOL` just comes out as is. There are other #defines but all of them follow the 3rd format in original post: `#define PREFIX_SOMETHING WRAPPER_MACRO(PFX_SOMETHING)` it basically just redoes the `PREFIX` to `PFX`.

Comment: @radj So the macros you posted in your question were copied directly from your codebase? You might want to edit your question to mention that, since the general assumption seems to be that those weren't the actual macros.

Comment: This is not the actual verbatim code from my codebase but it has the same template. I just replaced macro names.